# Access denied when using RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, mysite

I want regular user can access the "User Information List" in Mysite root site. I am using "RunWithElevatedPrivileges"  method. Still throwing access denied error. per example my root site collection for mysite is "http://network.test.com". the user want assess userinformation list this site collection. How can he access that?

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
 {
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.ID))
   {

   ServerContext sc = ServerContext.Current;
   UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(sc);
   UserProfile up = null;
   //get current user's profile (visitor)
   if (upm.UserExists(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName))
   {
       up =upm.GetUserProfile(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);

      SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
      SPList userInformationList = web.Lists["User Information List"];
```

Comment: did you run the code in the server that contain the SharePoint ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SPContext.Current` runs outside the `RunWithelevatedPrivileges` elevated context. For more info see [this](http://www.mikhaildikov.com/2007/07/runwithelevatedprivileges-watch-out-for.html) blog post.

Answer (score 6):

You're setting your SPWeb to SPContext.Current.Web, this doesn't have elevated privileges. Only SPWebs created from SPSites created inside the delegate are elevated.

So you need to replace

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
```

with

```
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're setting your SPWeb to SPContext.Current.Web this doesn't have elevated privileges.
Refer this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sasohail/archive/2010/10/31/access-denied-within-spsecurity-runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx):